# How to return multiple results from the Google Maps geocoding API?

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api

The [Google Maps API Geocoding Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses) page shows an example of how to geocode an address.

How can I return multiple address suggestions, so that I can pick the correct response?

For example, a search for "Richmond" should return multiple Richmonds across the world. However, this request only returns a single response (when I use a valid [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Richmond&key=YOUR_API_KEY

[image]

The example given at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes even suggests that multiple results should be returned for `address=Toledo` but I'm still only seeing one result for Toledo.

Is there a parameter to specify the number of results to return?

Comment: @Luke thanks for the tip - in this case I'd argue that the input is definitely 'ambiguous' and it should return multiple results. Adding `&components=country:au` or `&region=au` still doesn't help, although there are multiple Richmonds in Australia. Also see my edit regarding the Toledo search, which only returns 1 result for me

Comment: Looks like someone [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34628171) and didn't get an answer. The [Google Maps API blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) suggests you might want to look at the Places API as the Geocoding API is more for complete postal address strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34628171) and didn't get an answer. The [Google Maps API blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) says:

> The Geocoding API is best for handling unambiguous queries such as complete
>   postal address strings... Geocoding API is not
>   recommended if your application handles ambiguous or incomplete
>   queries

and suggests you might want to look at the Places API as the Geocoding API is more for complete postal address strings.